# Queries with conditional queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say i have a query with quite a number of joins and subqueries in one php file that handles queries.
Nb: i put an example of what $query looks like at the bottom

```
$query = query here;
if ($query) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Then in my php file that handles the html, i have the usual foreach loop with some conditions that require making other queries e.g;
Note: result houses object $query->result().

```
foreach ($results as $item) {
        $some_array = array();
        $some_id = $item->id;
        if ($some_id != 0) {
            //id_return_other_id is a function that querys a db table and returns the specified column in the same table, it returns just one field
            $other_id = id_return_other_id($some_id);
            $some_query = another  query that requires some joins and a subquery;
            $some_array = the values that are returned from some_query in an array
            //here i'm converting obj post into an array so i can merge the data in $some_array to item(Which was converted into an array) then convert all of it back into an object
            $item = (object)array_merge($some_array, (array)$item);
        }

//do the usual dynamic html stuff here.
}
```

This works perfectly but  as i don't like the way i'm doing lot's of queries in a loop, is there a way to add the if $some_id != 0 in the file that handles queries?
I've tried

```
$query = query here;
//declaring some array as empty when some_id is 0
$some_array = array();
if ($query) {
            if ($some_id != 0) {
            //same as i said before
            $other_id = $this->id_return_other_id($some_id);
            $some_query = some query;
            $some_array = array values gotten from some query;

        }
          $qresult = (object)array_merge($some_array, (array)$query->result);
          return $qresult;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

This doesn't work for obvious reasons, does any one have any ideas?

Also if there's a way to make these conditions and queries in the $query itself i'd love you forever.

Ps: A demo query would be something like

```
    $sql = "SELECT  p.*,up.*,upi.someField,etc..
                    FROM    (
                             SELECT  (another subquery)
                             FROM    table1
                             WHERE   table1_id = 3
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT  $user_id
                            ) uf
                    JOIN    table2 p
                    ON      p.id = uf.user_id
                    LEFT JOIN   table3 up
                    ON     .....
                    LEFT JOIN table4
                    ON     ....
                    LEFT JOIN table5
                    ON     ....
                    And so on..etc..
                    ORDER BY p.date DESC";
$query = mysql_query..
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks Neal, i didn't actually use mysql_ persay, i'm using active record and i just put that on there to explain what i mean :) Do you have any idea how i could go about the problem i have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just need to run two queries in your query file. The first query would get a broad set of what you’re looking for. The second query would query an id that’s in the result and perform a new query to get any details about that particular id. I use something similar to this in the customer search page for my application.

```
$output = array();

$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM...WHERE id = ...");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row1)
{
    $output[$row1['some_id']] = $row1;

    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {$row1['some_id']}");

    foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row2)
    {
        $output[$row1['some_id']]['data_details'][$row2['id']] = $row2;
    }
}
```

Then in your page that displays html, you’ll just need two foreaches:

```
foreach($queryresult as $key=> $field)
{
    echo $field['some_field'];

    foreach($child['data_details'] as $subkey => $subfield)
    {
        echo $subfield['some_subfield'];
    }
}
```

I know you’re using objects, but you could probably convert this to use that format. I hope this makes sense/helps.

Comment: Thank youu, it worked!!. Doesn't having a loop within a loop slow down the query?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 if ($some_id !== 0) {
```

instead of

```
 if ($some_id != 0) {
```

Comment: Nah, it's not the problem. Thanks tho :)